# Как исправить ошибку "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs"?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Есть проект с двумя активностями, при попытке запуска которого сообщается об ошибке: "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs". Вот сам манифест:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Lesson20221122"
        tools:targetApi="31" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowActivity"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Я попробовал рефакторинг на AndroidX - это не помогло. В чем заключается проблема?

Comment: В ошибке написано "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs", приложите логи, чтобы понять, в чем проблема.

Comment: Имеется ввиду "Event logs"? Все, что там есть при запуске студии и при запуске приложения:
17:07 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

17:07 * daemon started successfully

17:09 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\projects\app

17:09 Gradle build failed in 30 s 628 ms

Comment: Затем выводится сообщение "Gradle build failed". Почему это могло произойти?

Comment: Поищите [логи](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41337748) в файле `app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt` и [приложите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1474461/edit) логи в ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы исправить ошибку, нужно сначала определить, в чем проблема. В тексте ошибки указано, что детали ошибки находятся в логах.

Для debug-сборки ошибки логируются в файл:

```
app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt
```

А для release-сборки смотрите файл:

```
app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-release-report.txt
```